# Remove one Ubuntu installation using another

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I have two installations of Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop, and I want to get rid of one of them. How can I remove one of them? I've seen a lot of answers to related questions, but they all deal with how to install from a startup disk or something like that, and wipe the hard drive. I want to keep one installation of Ubuntu, and remove the other.

Comment: MayBe Gparted ?

Comment: Try using boot repair disk, it can uinstall one of the operating systems. It comes in an iso file and you must use a program like unetbootin to make it bootable

Answer (score 3):

So, you have *Ubuntu A* and *Ubuntu B*. Let's say you boot up in *Ubuntu A* that you want to keep.

Open GParted, unmount partition with *Ubuntu B* then select swap partition of *Ubuntu B* (if any), right-click on it and choose swapoff. **Swapoff** is important, so don't miss it. Select partition with *Ubuntu B* and delete that partition. Apply changes.

Open a Terminal window and type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Close Terminal and reboot. After restart, only one Ubuntu (ex-A) should appear in the boot menu.

Comment: What do you mean by "swap partition"?

Comment: `sudo: update: command not found` didn't work.

Comment: Swap partition is a special kind of partition used by linux operating systems as virtual RAM memory. When physical RAM memory is totally (100%) used, virtual RAM comes up to help it and expand total RAM capacity. Same type of things happens in Windows too, but Windows uses empty space on C:\ as virtual RAM. When C:\ is full, no more virtual RAM is available and Windows get stuck in certain situations. Having virtual RAM as dedicated space/partition prevents linux from getting stuck.

Comment: Any Ubuntu installation should automatically create a swap partition. But some users delete that because various reasons (huge physical RAM, insufficient disk space, using external device as swap-virtual RAM, or simply because self-ignorance).

Comment: please correct the command, you should have `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @Michal: Thanks for your pertinent observation. The wise man is right: big things do get stuck in small details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GParted to format the partition and then run an upgrade grub command to update bootloader that the partition no longer has an OS.

Answer (score 0):

If the two installation are on separate partitions and don't have any common mount points like `/home` or `/bin`,  you can pretty much safely format the unwanted partition and generate new grub menu entries.